# c++ fstream dosent work after 1 function (by refrence)

Tags: c++, file, iostream, fstream

Hi im trying to count the amount of lines and amount of chars in a txt file, after 1 function that counts the lines (it works) the char counter dosent work but if i use the the char counter alone it works. (i know i can mix it to one function but i have a bigger problem that this example will fix)

Main:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream isf("D:\\test.txt", ios_base::in);
    ofstream osf("D:\\test.txt", fstream::app);
    //WriteToFile(osf,isf);
    cout << CountLines(isf)<< endl;
    cout << CountChar(isf) <<endl;
    isf.close();
    osf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

the functions:

```
const int CountLines(ifstream& isf)
{
    int count = 1;
    char c;
    while (isf.get(c))
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
const int CountChar(ifstream& isf)
{
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    while (isf.get(c))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

the txt file:

```
abc
abc
```

the output:

```
2
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and the output should be

```
2
7
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the stream to the starting position after calling the 1st function:

```
cout << CountLines(isf)<< endl;
isf.clear(); // Reset stream states like eof()
isf.seekg(0); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
cout << CountChar(isf) <<endl;
```

Comment: @Rokni How _"it doesn't work"_ specifically? Maybe adding a `isf.clear()` may help to reset the stream state completely.

Comment: it doesnt work but when i change their order it does. il edit your post and mark it as an answer thank you you just need to review the edit :)